# Need Facebook solution to refresh cached open graph image paths for thousands of pages

Tags: image, debugging, caching, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

We've updated our open graph image (og:image) meta tag with new image paths but Facebook is still showing our Web site's default logo image -- seemingly cached from our initial Like button implementation. We're referring to the image that shows in the Facebook Like/Share dialog when the user clicks the Like button.

We have run an automated job to have Facebook's debug tool (e.g: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?format=json&q=http://www.domain.com) crawl through all of our pages with updated image paths, but Facebook's debug tool (or site) is blocking our automated job by returning a redirect to http://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser. Please note that we have about 62,500 pages that need to be crawled in order to have the og:image meta tag content attribute refreshed with the latest image paths.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear Facebook like button cached information](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8217404/how-to-clear-facebook-like-button-cached-information)

Comment: The solution to our problem was actually by passing an agent value to Facebook's debugger in order to have Facebook not redirect us to their "unsupported browser" page, which in turn made the request unsuccessful  

cURL User Agent Solution:
`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');`

http://davidwalsh.name/set-user-agent-php-curl-spoof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to our problem was actually by passing an agent value to Facebook's debugger in order to have Facebook not redirect us to their "unsupported browser" page, which in turn made the request unsuccessful.

**cURL User Agent Solution**

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');`

See: http://davidwalsh.name/set-user-agent-php-curl-spoof

Comment: You'll still encounter problems if it's noticed that you're scraping a website endpoint instead of using the API